# How to query the capability of the audio output channel configuration via Android API?

Tags: audio, config, channel

I am writing a sound player to play multi-channel audio files, and I need to know whether the running Android device can physically support multi-channel playback. I mean the final output will not be downmix to 2.0 stereo.

Is there an API to get this information?

For example, some devices can play audio via the MHL or HDMI interface, in this case, the query result of multi-channel should return true.
And some devices will always mixdown audio to stereo, in this case, the result should return false.

Thanks~